# div element is getting appended outside the body

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to implement a list on right-click of a data node. In order to do so I came across d3-context-menu plugin of d3.js. The problem I am facing is that the div element is getting appened outside the body tag.

[image]

I have never seen such an issue before. 
I am following the plugin example given here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hAx36JQhb0RsvVn7TomS?p=preview

This is the link to the library documentation:
https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu

I have no clue why it is behaving in such manner. My code structure looks like this :

```
eventGroup = focusClip.selectAll(".event").data(data);

// Enter phase ---
eventGroupEnter = eventGroup.enter().append("svg");
eventGroupEnter.append("rect");
eventGroupEnter.append("circle");
eventGroupEnter.append("text");

// Event Group
eventGroup
  .attr("class", "event")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return parseInt(x(d.time)) - 10;
  }) // offset for the bg and center of dot
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return parseInt(y(d.plotY));
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return parseInt((d.label.length / 2)) + 60 + "em";
  })
  .attr("height", "20");

// Background
eventGroup.select("rect")
  .attr("x", 0) // removes the "<rect> attribute x: Expected length, 'NaN'" Error
  .attr("y", 4)
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "12")
  .attr("fill", "url(#event-bg)");

menu = [{
  title: "Item #1"
}];
// Dot
eventGroup.select("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("cx", 10)
  .attr("cy", 10)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d.evtColor ? d.evtColor : "#229ae5";
  })
  .attr("stroke", function(d) {
    return d.evtColor ? d.evtColor : "#229ae5";
  })
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .on("contextmenu", d3.contextMenu(menu, function() {
    console.log("Quick! Before the menu appears!");
  }))
  .on("mouseenter", tooltip.mouseover)
  .on("mouseleave", tooltip.mouseout)
  .on("click", annotateBox.click);
```

In order to explain it well I am adding the image of the chart:
[image]

The right click event is being called on the "dot" part of the event. Why would div element get appended outside the body?

Comment: Please share the link to the plugin documentation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to the plugin. I had a (very) quick look but I didn't find any clue. If this is a bug, maybe you get a proper answer opening a Github issue. Just confirming, are you using D3 v3?

Comment: Yes I am using d3 v3.

Comment: I had a better look at the documentation, now I see that that plunker is the official one. So, this seems to be by design, as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be by design. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu/blob/master/js/d3-context-menu.js) of that plugin, you'll see:

```
d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').data([1])
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'd3-context-menu');
```

Since `selectAll` is called on the root, the div will be appended to the `<html>`, not to the `<body>`.

So, the author either did this intentionally or she/he forgot that `d3.selectAll` is different from `selection.selectAll`.

Here is a basic demo, click "Run code snippet", open your browser's dev tools and inspect the snippet window.

```js
d3.selectAll("foo")
  .data([1])
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "test")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

You're gonna see this:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>...</body>
    <div class="test"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: ok so you are suggesting that this is the intended behavior ? because even in that case I am getting double scroll bars on the right suggesting that the d3-context-menu is running in background of the rest of the implementation.

Comment: I don't know if that's intended, what I'm saying is that this is the expected result given the source code. You can open a Github issue asking this to the author.

Comment: Ok thanks! I have asked the question on github. Will update here if I get any response.

Comment: @user2128 Good to know. However, you may have a different problem here. As I said in my answer, appending in the `<html>` is the default behaviour of that plugin, as you can see in their **working** plunker. However, you described a different problem in your GitHub issue. So, your problem probably has no relation with the div being outside the body... you said *" I feel that could be the reason of list not appearing"* but that's not the case, since their plunker **is** working.

Comment: That being said, I suggest you accept this answer or delete this question, and post *another* question with the same description you provided on the GitHub issue.